# custom dialog not showing up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, dialog

I'm trying to make a custom dialog but it is not showing up.[image]

this is how it looks like when I click at the button to show the dialog

and this is my dialog class and the mainActivity

---

### this is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button click;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        click = findViewById(R.id.click);
        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                AddUserDialog dialog = new AddUserDialog();
                dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MyCustomDialog");

            }
        });
    }



}
```

---

this is my AddUserDialog

---

```
public class AddUserDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public Button add;
    public EditText userName, UserEmail, userPhone;
   /* public ImageView addPhoto;*/
    public TextView cancel;


    @NonNull
    protected View onCreate(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_user_dialog, container, false);

        add = v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        cancel = v.findViewById(R.id.cancel_dialog);
        userName = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        UserEmail = v.findViewById(R.id.email);
        userPhone = v.findViewById(R.id.phone);
       /* addPhoto = v.findViewById(R.id.addPhoto);
*/
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Snackbar.make(v, "User added", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });

        return v;

    }


}
```

did I miss something in my scenario, please advise me and thank you.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: That method name in your `AddUserDialog` class should be `onCreateView()`, not `onCreate()`. It also should be `public`, not `protected`. Using the `@Override` annotation might've tipped you off that you've got the wrong thing, there.

Comment: OMG, how I did that !!!! Thank you

Comment: I am out of focus these days :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `AddUserDialog` to

```
public class AddUserDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public Button add;
    public EditText userName, UserEmail, userPhone;
    /* public ImageView addPhoto;*/
    public TextView cancel;

    static AddUserDialog newInstance() {
        AddUserDialog f = new AddUserDialog();
        return f;
    }

    @NonNull
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_user_dialog, container, false);

        add = v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        cancel = v.findViewById(R.id.cancel_dialog);
        userName = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        UserEmail = v.findViewById(R.id.email);
        userPhone = v.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        /* addPhoto = v.findViewById(R.id.addPhoto);
         */
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Snackbar.make(v, "User added", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

and call the dialog

```
AddUserDialog dialog = AddUserDialog.newInstance();
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MyCustomDialog");
```

Answer (score 0):

it works for me, use onCreateDialog

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
   View dialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_picker_dialog, null);

    ////your code here 
    pickerDay = dialog.findViewById(R.id.picker_day);
    pickerMonth = dialog.findViewById(R.id.picker_month);
    pickerYear = dialog.findViewById(R.id.picker_year);
    //////////

    builder.setView(dialog);
    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Your OnClick() . Use this

```
AddUserDialo userDialog = new AddUserDialo ( MainActivity.this );
                userdDialog.getWindow ().setBackgroundDrawable ( new ColorDrawable ( Color.TRANSPARENT ) );
                userdDialog.show ();
```

Comment: the mistake was in the (AddUserDialog Class) I was using protected onCreate instead of public onCreateView